# what is difference between "update" method of Session class and "executeupdate" method of Query class in hibernate, when which method use?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

what is difference between "update" method of Session class  and "executeupdate" method of Query   class in hibernate, when which method use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: [`Session.update()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html) is used to **update a single** mapped entity; with [`Query.executeupdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29) you can perform custom delete/update statement (written is HQL or pure SQL) and get as result the updated/deleted entities count.
Which is the right method depends which is your need: with `executeupdate()` you can delete/update an arbitrary number of objects based on a query, with `update()` you can only update one single object at time.

Comment: yes, i try that we can make a update query and update our necessary field using "executeUpdate"...  and in "Update" We have to update whole entity field.

Answer (score 2):

The two methods work at a different level of abstraction:

- **[update](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#update%28java.lang.Object%29)** Basically takes it's parameter entity, finds a row in it's table with the same primary key and issues an `UPDATE` so that after you commit your transaction, the row has all the information your parameter object had. In addition, the update is cascaded to all dependent objects if they were annotated/marked with `cascade = save-update`.
- **[executeUpdate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29)** will parse the query you created (which should be an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement) and issues it to the database. No cascading or other logic is executed.

When to use which depends on your needs, as bellabax said: `executeUpdate` is useful for updating a specific table and several rows, but I prefer the simplicity of `update` if I don't work with severe time constraints (issuing several database `UPDATE`s will be slower).

Answer (score 0):

executeUpdate allows you to run a native SQL query which can be not supported by Hibernate. For example, you need to update with certain conditions.

Using executeUpdate is more powerful but do not use it within a Hibernate transaction. Give a method as below:

```
    @@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void updateLastActivity(VaultUserImpl user, Date lastActivity) {
    Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("UPDATE VaultUserImpl user set user.lastActivity=:lastActivity where user.id=:id");
    query.setDate("lastActivity", lastActivity);
    query.setLong("id", user.getId());
    query.executeUpdate();

    user.setLastActivity(lastActivity);
}
```

By default, Hibernate will call update method automatically within a transaction annotation. That means the query above is not only necessary but dangereux because we lost data.

In fact,  query.setDate(Date datetime) does not return full date+time value but date only.

The code above can be write shortly:

```
    @@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void updateLastActivity(VaultUserImpl user, Date lastActivity) {
    user.setLastActivity(lastActivity);
}
```